# Inserindo uma página de um site dentro de outra

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, cms

Tenho um site desenvolvido em um CMS e em uma certa página deste site, preciso inserir uma outra página que foi desenvolvida sem o auxílio do CMS. Para ser mais preciso, essa página que estou tentando incorporar em meu site, é uma tabela de preços dinâmica, que utiliza a linguagem **HTML** e **JavaScript**.

Tendo em vista que este meu site CMS foi todo desenvolvido com o auxílio de um plugin que trabalha com shortcodes. Neste plugin existe um shortcode em que é possível adicionar um código HTML.

Sabendo disso, pesquisei maneiras de como incorporar essa página (tabela de preços) dentro do meu site CMS.

A primeira alternativa que encontrei, foi através do **iframe**, no entanto ao tentar acessar a página do site, o navegador informa que aquela página está tentando carregar scripts de fontes não seguras, e acaba "bloqueando" o frame onde a tabela seria exibida, deixando apenas um espaço em branco. É possível habilitar o site para carregar scripts não seguros, no entanto é preciso clicar em um "escudo" muito discreto que fica no canto superior direito do navegador, o que é um ponto negativo para os visitantes do site.

Já a segunda alternativa, seria copiar o código html inteiro da tabela de preços, e inserí-lo no shortcode, da mesma maneira como foi inserido o iframe.
Na tentativa de inserir o código inteiro na página, percebi que ao carregar a página todo a formatação que havia no layout do site, foi desconfigurada, acredito que por algum conflito de css/folha de estilos.

Portanto, faço os seguintes questionamentos:

- É possível inserir a tabela por IFrame sem que o navegador bloqueie o conteúdo por conta do aviso de "que o site está tentando carregar scripts de fontes não seguras"?
- Se por IFrame não for possível, como que eu posso fazer para resolver esse problema de desconfiguração do layout do site, quando é inserida a tabela de preços?

Deixo aqui a página da tabela:
https://piscinafacil.com.br/tabela2.html

E a página do site CMS em que estou tentando incorporar a tabela:
https://piscinafacil.com.br/residenciais/

Ficarei agradecido se alguém puder me dar uma luz nesse problema.
:)

Comment: o link para residenciais dá erro 404

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode utilizar iFrame, ou jQuery com Ajax para chamar essa pagina.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'SUA URL'
  success: function(data){//}
});
```

Comment: Opa Rafael! Obrigado pela atenção!

Me desculpe a ignorância no assunto, mas não tenho experiência com jQuery. Como se trata de um site CMS, acredito que tenha alguma limitação para inserir jQuery com Ajax. Eu conseguirei inserir este código jQuery através de um shortcode HTML?

Comment: Sim, consegue sim

Comment: Basta eu copiar aquele código ali? Como insiro ele em um html? desculpa a ignorância, mas não tenho nenhum conhecimento de jQuery

Comment: Nao tem problema, é so voce colocar ele dentro de um script no HTML <script></script> lembrando que tem que ter o jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Olha, estou usando o Chrome 67 e com iframe funcionou... abri o segundo link, pra mim deu um erro 404, mas editei pelo inspetor de código e no lugar da mensagem de erro inseri o iframe sem problemas, do mesmo jeito que abrindo diretamente:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <iframe src="https://piscinafacil.com.br/tabela2.html" width="100%" height="900"></iframe>
</div>
```

O único problema que tive foi nos caracteres ², que pra mim aqui aparecem como `ÃÂ²`. Provavelmente o javascript está pegando valores que não são UTF-8, ou se for um javascript separado veja se está salvo em UTF-8.